# Advanced SQL Select Query (unique rows) (group by)

Tags: mysql, sql

My DB is saving phone calls that my company makes.
I need to make a select query that selects all unique persons and for each person it should select:

- Number of inbound calls
- Number of outbound calls
- Total calls
- Average calltime

I tried this and got stuck on selecting inbound and outbound calls.
Ill explain how to see when a call is inbound or outbound.

When `OriginationDevice` is filled its a inbound call for `DestinationName`. 
When `DestinationDevice` is filled its a outbound call for `OriginationName`.

I need every Unique `DestinationName` or `OriginationName` and list the number of inbound, outbound and total calls and of course the average calltime.
I've came far but I can't seem to get inbound and outbound in one query.

Check out my [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c13d032/1) where you can play with to help me!
Can anyone help me get the average calltime, outbound calls, inbound calls and total calls for each person?

My Query attempt:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT 
   IFNULL (SUM( CASE WHEN OriginationDevice != '' AND ConnectTime != '' THEN 
   DATEDIFF(ConnectTime, EndTime) ELSE null END ) /  COUNT(case when 
   OriginationDevice <> '' then 1 else null end), 0) as calltime,
   COUNT(case when OriginationDevice != '' then 1 else null end) as inbound,
   COUNT(case when DestinationDevice != '' AND OriginationDevice = '' then 1 
   else null end) as outbound,
   COUNT(*) as total,
   DestinationName

   FROM calls WHERE (YEAR(EndTime) = 2018 AND MONTH(EndTime) = 12) and 
   (OriginationDevice != '' or DestinationDevice != '')
   AND ConnectTime != ''  GROUP BY DestinationName
) as t1
WHERE total > 0  ORDER BY total DESC, calltime
```

This is the table sql:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `calls` (
  `OriginationName` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `DestinationName` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `ConnectTime` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `EndTime` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `OriginationDevice` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `DestinationDevice` varchar(200) NOT NULL
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `calls` (`OriginationName`, `DestinationName`, `ConnectTime`, `EndTime`, `OriginationDevice`, `DestinationDevice`) VALUES
  ('Person 1', 'Person 5', '2018-12-11 11:26:12', '2018-12-11 11:26:18', '243', '(call routing)'),
  ('Person 2', 'Person 3', '2018-12-11 10:16:12', '2018-12-11 10:16:54', '', '(call routing)'),
  ('Person 5', 'Person 1', '2018-12-11 10:21:12', '2018-12-11 10:22:22', '', ''),
   ('Person 2', 'Person 1', '2018-12-11 11:26:12', '2018-12-11 11:26:52', '233', ''),
    ('Person 1', 'Person 4', '2018-12-11 12:26:12', '2018-12-11 12:28:25', '456', ''),
     ('', 'Person 1', '2018-12-11 14:56:12', '2018-12-11 14:57:24', '', '(call routing)'),
  ('Person 3', '', '2018-12-11 15:26:12', '2018-12-11 15:26:37', '223', '');
```

My expected result is in the query.

Comment: SQLfiddle is great, but put sample data and the expected result here too, and your query attempt as well. (Formatted text, not images.)

Comment: Your SQL Fiddle doesn't work for me, so I cannot see the data.

Comment: How is that possible? How does it work for me then? I added the query and table sql to the question

Comment: Ill check if there are any answers tomorrow ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one should do what you ask :

```
 SELECT 
    Person,
    SUM(case when typology = 'outbounds' then calls_number else 0 end) as outbounds,
    SUM(case when typology = 'inbounds' then calls_number else 0 end) as inbounds,
    SUM(calls_number) as calls_number,
    case when SUM(calls) = 0 then 0 else SUM(callTime) / SUM(calls) end as avgCallTime
FROM(
SELECT 
    OriginationName as Person,
    SUM(case 
        when DestinationDevice != '' and ConnectTime != '' then (EndTime - ConnectTime) 
        else 0 end
    ) as callTime,
    SUM(case when DestinationDevice != '' then 1 else 0 end) as calls_number,
    'outbounds' as typology
FROM calls 
WHERE (YEAR(EndTime) = 2018 AND MONTH(EndTime) = 12) and ConnectTime != ''
    and OriginationName != ''
GROUP BY OriginationName
    union
SELECT 
    DestinationName,
    SUM(case 
        when OriginationDevice != '' and ConnectTime != '' then (EndTime - ConnectTime) 
        else 0 end
    ),
    SUM(case when OriginationDevice  != ''  then 1 else 0 end),
    'inbounds' as typology
FROM calls 
WHERE (YEAR(EndTime) = 2018 AND MONTH(EndTime) = 12) and ConnectTime != '' 
    and DestinationName != ''
GROUP BY DestinationName) as T
GROUP BY Person;
```

Let me know if there is something wrong, this sample work https://sqltest.net/#386096

Comment: What names should I change to my DB name? I changed my original DB name into `calls`

Comment: So calls should change in my own DB name, in which places?

Comment: Thanks anyway, it helped me a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the question, tables names are the string after the `FROM` key word, you can change the **calls** string here. You can modify the alias given to the number of call to in the `SELECT` part too, I recognize that give the same name to column and table can be confused, i will adjust this on the answer.